# How can I display result in order of hierarchy (in Oracle SQL Developer)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset where first column is employee code and second column is manager code. I am trying to output an extract where reporting structure is clearly visible. How can I do that? I would appreciate any clues. Below are sample dataset and expected output.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuZa9.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbmhm.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need a CONNECT BY clause and LPAD function combination -

```
 SELECT LPAD('*', LEVEL - 1, '*') || col_org Col_hierarchy_org
   FROM DATA D
  START WITH col_org_predecessor IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR col_org = col_org_predecessor;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5a5e15a02fa2866564189b6a634e6130)